# How can I show the details from the highest zoom of OSM webmaps in QGIS for printing?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I would like to compose a large format map for printing in QGIS with the highest detail possible.  My process looks like this,

1. Install "QuickMapServices" plugin
2. Click the "QuickMapServices" button and choose OSM >> OSM Standard
3. Pan to my selection area
4. New print layout (ctrl + p) and make a name
5. add item >> add map (its now at the zoom where I want more detail displayed and I don't know what to do).

Comment: If you increase the export resolution, QGIS will export the zoom level of the basemap that gives you that resolution. See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/292751/81764) where the asker is trying to figure out how to *stop* QGIS from changing the zoom level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must increase either the page size, the export resolution, or both.

To change the page size right-click the layout --> go to *Page Properties* --> select or define a larger page dimension in the Item Properties panel (screen-right by default).

The export resolution may be changed at the time of (image) export, or within the Layout panel under *Export Settings*.

QGIS 3.2 (older versions as well) fetches images from a tile server at the time of screen render as well as at export/print. Screen-space tiles are fetched for the layout preview while page-space tiles are fetched at the time of export. Therefor, the layout preview will not reflect the higher-zoom map.

There are upper bounds to the exportable image size and QGIS will warn you if the operation will result in a memory overflow. Additionally, the process of fetching a large number of tiles can take a long time.

Below are the results of an OSM tile map preview and export of an Arch E @ 450dpi.

[image: Map Layout preview image]

[image: Map export image]